# I've created a github repository and am now trying to clone it, however when doing so I receive this, cd: no such file or directory. How do i fix it?

Tags: github, repository

I'm trying to create a study guide for my coursework on mac and it requires me to generate an ssh key(this has been done),however now I have to create a repository and clone it.

```
Cloning into 'prework-study-guide-'...
cd: no such file or directory: prework-study-guide
```

^I've created and cloned the repo however I receive an error in my termnial saying no such file or directory.

Comment: What commands did you use to get this output?

Answer (score 0):

You probably are in the wrong directory or have the wrong file name. Try changing the directory or name. Also, please try putting more information about the error.

Have a nice day